# spud-blog grails plugin not working with spring-security config?

Tags: grails

I'm using `Grails 2.4.4` with `Spring Security Plugin 2.0.0` on a project to which I have just added `spud-blog 0.5.2`.

According to the [short documentation on github](https://github.com/spud-grails/spud-blog) I could go to http://localhost:8080/myapp/spud/admin immediately after including the plugin.

The problem is that somehow I am getting a `403` when accessing the URL above, even though I have

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/spud/admin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/spud/**':       ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    ...
]
```

and I am logging in with a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` role.

I have tried changing the rules to `'permitAll'` but still no luck.

EDIT:
Apparently I do have to add `grails-security-bridge` and configure it.

I've followed http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-security-bridge/guide/configuration.html and https://gist.github.com/marcpalmer/2225545

Yet still no luck. I must be missing something?

Comment: Are any of your other spring security URL rules working? Why aren't you using `grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap` instead? That looks a bit suspect to me. What's your `securityConfigType` set to?

Comment: I am not using `grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap` because I want to lock down some things (like static resources and stuff) in Config.groovy but use annotations in my controllers. From your comment I get the impression I would not be able to use spud-blog while using annotations and `controllerAnnotations.staticRules`?
Does that mean that if I want to have security via annotations I have to make a custom spud admin controller?